# Delphi - Can indy TIdTCPClient Send/Receive large streams at the same time

Tags: delphi, indy

Is it possible to Send/Receive large streams at the same time with **TIdTCPServer/TIdTCPClient** with the same client.

I have create a thread on the client side to handle the incoming requests.

Client receive the request but it will not send it back to the server until the previous requite finished (sent or received).

Comment: Without seeing an MCVE, it's impossible to know what's going wrong in your code. A single thread can only process one request at a time. If you want to process multiple requests simultaneously, you'll need more than one thread, perhaps a thread pool. This is also unrelated to the server, the server might not even be Indy, and might not even be in Delphi. It's only the client side you're concerned about.

Comment: @JerryDodge Each request processed by a separate thread.

Comment: Then back to my first sentence, we can't see how you've written your code, therefore it's impossible for us to answer to your issue. Provide an MCVE which demonstrates your issue, and we can work off of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to Send/Receive large streams at the same time with TIdTCPServer/TIdTCPClient with the same client.

Yes, it is *possible*.  But *how* you do it depends on your protocol implementation.  TCP sockets are bi-directional and full-duplex.  You could have one thread sending while another thread is receiving.  Or you can break up your streams into blocks so one thread can send a block, read a block, send a block, read a block, etc.

> I have create a thread on the client side to handle the incoming requests.
>
> Client receive the request but it will not send it back to the server until the previous requite finished (sent or received).

This implies that you are doing your processing in a single thread, and doing the entire processing one request at a time in a serial manner, where you are not reading the next request from the connection until the previous response has been sent first.  While this is the *typical* model, it might not be the *right* model, depending on your particular needs.

Comment: can he do the send and revive on the same port?

Comment: @remy-lebeau Do you recommend of creating `array of TIdTCPClient` to handle each a new request if the main **TIdTCPClient** is still sending?. or its a bad implementation. if you recommend that. Should the server also use `array of TIdTCPServer` ? i know the tcpserver is multithreading but i mean if the same client connect to the same server using multi `TIdTCPClient` is the server still works with that client on separated threads for each `TIdTCPClient` i appreciating your answer.

Comment: Again, it depends on your particular protocol design.  If the server will allow multiple connections from the same client PC, then fine, but just note that you will be using more server resources so they will not be available for other clients. But definitely do not use an array of servers. Like you said yourself, `TIdTCPServer` is multi-threaded. Each `TIdTCPClient` connection will be a new thread, so you can use a single server.